# ¿Cómo aumentar el tamaño de la fuente en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, vistas

Quiero aumentar el tamaño de la fuente en el apartado donde modifico el código, ¿dónde modifico el tamaño de la fuente en Android Studio?

Comment: Para los que quieren cerrar esta pregunta porque "no está claro lo que se pregunta":  ¿El que no se entiende de "dónde modifico el tamaño de la fuente en Android Studio"?

Comment: Perdón por la reversión. He editado una etiqueta que estaba bien por error y por eso la he realizado.

Comment: @Error404 - Ahora se entiende *mejor* después de las ediciones pero se podría cerrar ahora y anteriormente por: *no relacionado porque... Esta pregunta no parece versar sobre programación...*

Comment: @aldanux Ves, eso lo vería más razonable. Sin embargo, y dejando a un lado que he respondido a esta pregunta, creo que se debería de mantener abierta por el hecho de que, hasta dónde yo sé, también se puede preguntar sobre frameworks y aplicaciones que te sirven para programar (no sobre cual es mejor para utilizar, si no por algo concreto de las mismas). Y en este caso es una de ellas. De todas formas, puedo estar totalmente equivocado.

Answer (score 5):

Lo puedes realizar yendo a `File > Settings > Colors & Fonts` y creandote un nuevo nombre dándole al `Save as...`

Posteriormente puedes cambiar el tamaño de la letra yendo al apartado `Fonts` dentro de `Colors & Fonts` y cambiando el parámetro `Size`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para guardar los cambios tendrás que pulsar sobre el botón `Apply` y después sobre el botón `OK`.

---

Por otro lado, si lo que quisieras fuera solamente aumentar el tamaño del código momentáneamente podrías realizarlo dirigiéndote al apartado `File > Settings > General` y marcando la opción `Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera, podrás aumentar el tamaño del código pulsando la tecla  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> y moviendo la ruleta del ratón aunque el tamaño de letra que establezcas en este caso no se guardará para la próxima vez que abras `Android Studio`.

Answer (score 1):

En `Android Studio` es similar a `Intellij Idea`, se realiza mediante :

`Settings` > `Editor` > `Colors & fonts`

Al cambiar "Primary font" puedes ver una prevista de como se mostraría el texto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]